# Get all items in collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird

I'm trying to populate a db with some default dummy data in order to speed up testing. This is part of a project that uses https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack and I'm attempting to use promises for the first time.

Assuming I have something like:

```
Thing.create({
  name: 'thing 1'
}, {
  name: 'thing 2'
}).then((things) => {
  console.log(things);
});
```

Why does the console log only output `thing 1` and not the whole collection?

According to the mongoose docs http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create, the method returns a promise which doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: did you try with callback?

Comment: The use of the Promise is correct, prefer it over the callback. Remember setting Mongoose to use Promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Mongoose to return a `Promise` you need to set this accordingly in your Mongoose instance:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Furthermore, if you want to create multiple documents at once, you should pass an `array` to the `.create` method:

```
let things = [
  {
    "name": "Thing 1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Thing 2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Thing 3"
  }
];

Thing.create(things).then(newThings => {
  console.log(newThings);
});

// Outputs
[ { name: 'Thing 1', _id: 57fd82973b4a85be9da73b25 },
  { name: 'Thing 2', _id: 57fd82973b4a85be9da73b26 },
  { name: 'Thing 3', _id: 57fd82973b4a85be9da73b27 } ]
```